# Yii2 restful API with data access objects instead of active record

Tags: php, rest, yii2

According to docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html use active record is the recommended way to implement restful api in Yii2.

The thing is a I want to avoid active record and use data access object (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html) instead, and I'm looking for a example.

Comment: I do not believe SO works like that. This is off-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use base [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-controller.html) and construct new action for DAO. See on the [rest folder](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework/rest) and rewrite actions.